# tracking visitors after they have left my site

Tags: cookies, tracking

Just wondering if it is possible to track what the user does on other sites. Say for example a user comes to my site and I track his actions with a cookie. Now is there any way that I can track this user's activities after they have left my site?

Comment: You really have no business tracking what people are doing on other sites.

Comment: If there is, then once the method becomes known it will be patched quicker than lightning, as it would be one of the bigger security holes these days. So basically, you can't do this without installing spyware on the users computer.

Comment: but why can't I be evil grrr - I am not employing these dirty tactics though. Just looking for confirmation that its not possible, after hearing the manager saying it is...

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible since cookies are being tied to domain they are being set in. [HTTP State Management RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html) has more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible? Not that I think it's an ethical thing to do, but could some javascript event handler be established in hidden window to note when navigation events occur? Send info back to originating server? Might not be reliable but maybe some snooping is possible?

Oh, and there's this: http://static.whattheinternetknowsaboutyou.com/results.html

Comment: Script could not figure out anything ... but script was working hard for a minute or so :-)